# Is there a rational explanation for this PHP call-by-value behavior? Or PHP bug?

Tags: php, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

PHP 5.5.12. Consider this:

```
<?php
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
foreach($a as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);
```

This, as expected, outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aq
    [1] => bq
    [2] => cq
)
```

Now consider:

```
<?php
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
foreach(z($a) as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);

function z($a)
{
    return $a;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aq
    [1] => bq
    [2] => cq
)
```

(!) But wait a minute. $a is not being passed by reference. Which means I should be getting a copy back from z(), which would be modified, and $a ought to be left alone.

But what happens when we force PHP to do its copy-on-write magic:

```
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
foreach(z($a) as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);

function z($a)
{
    $a[0] .= 'x';
    return $a;
}
```

For this, we get what I would expect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

EDIT: One more example...

```
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
$b = z($a);
foreach($b as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);

function z($a)
{
    return $a;
}
```

This works as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

Is there a rational explanation for this?

Comment: Looks to me like `$a` **is** being passed by reference in example #2. This is indeed different to what happens in PHP 5.4 ~ https://eval.in/172839. Might have something to do with the array dereferencing changes introduced in 5.5

Comment: Your last example is invalid. `$b = z($a);` is being applied to the whole array at once.

Comment: From [these results](http://3v4l.org/MIA2p) it should be obvious that you shouldn't actually rely on this behaviour; it could be a bug in fact.

Comment: Got another whacky example for you ~ https://eval.in/172857

Comment: To me, it's not **array** passed by reference to foreach, but **array elements** (one-by-one). From this point, all examples are correct.

Comment: @MichaelLivach Based on that, shouldn't the third example have been  `['axq', 'bq', 'cq']` then?

Comment: @Jack No, $a was copied with all elements here: `$b = z($a);`

Comment: @MichaelLivach The one with `$b` in it is the fourth example.

Comment: tried this: `<?php
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
$b = &z($a);
foreach($b as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);

function &z($a)
{
  return $a;
}` - got unmodified array. Agree, topicstarter found a bug.

Comment: @Jack, third - with `$a[0] .= 'x';` ? It's correct too: copy-on-write did full copy of $a$ the copy was lost after foreach() finished

Comment: @Jack, look at this example, please: `<?
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
$b = [ &$a[0], &$a[1], &$a[2] ];

foreach(z($b) as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);
print_r($b);

function z($v)
{
    $v[0] .= 'x';
    $v[3] = 'woo';
    return $v;
}
`

Comment: @MichaelLivach I don't see why you seem to think that such an example proves that this seems to be correct behaviour; you can clearly see from my earlier 3v4l comment that it doesn't work reliably across different versions of php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57387/discussion-between-michael-livach-and-jack).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. I agree that it seems to be a bug, but I wanted to be sure. PHP has fooled me before with odd semantics that was actually correct, documented behavior. :) I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: @Nairebis Just had a quick chat with another php-src developer and he agreed that it's a bug.

Comment: Reported as https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67633

Answer (score 9):

#### Update

Bug [67633](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67633) has been opened to address this issue. The behaviour has been changed by [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/de80e3ce4b5b7a9ec0cfdd0778e77027a7ebfcc2) in an effort to remove reference restrictions from foreach.

---

From [this 3v4l output](http://3v4l.org/MIA2p) you can clearly see that this behaviour has changed over time:

#### Update 2

Fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/5e977e69e144ca92868ae73cd3563eb473b75937); this will become available in 5.5.18 and 5.6.2.

#### PHP 5.4

Prior to PHP 5.5 your code would actually raise a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot create references to elements of a temporary array expression
```

#### PHP 5.5 - 5.6

These versions do not perform copy-on-write when the function result is used directly inside the `foreach` block. As such, the original array is now used and changes to the elements are permanent.

I personally feel that **this is a bug**; copy-on-write should have taken place.

#### PHP > 5.6

In the [phpng branch](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/phpng), which is likely to become the basis of a next major version, constant arrays are made immutable so the copy-on-write is correctly performed only in this case. Declaring the array like below will exhibit the same issue with phpng:

```
$foo = 'b';
$a = ['a', $foo, 'b'];
```

[Proof](http://3v4l.org/ahAqV)

#### Hack (HHVM)

Only Hack handles the situation correctly as it currently stands.

### The right way

The [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) way of using the function result by reference is this:

```
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
foreach(z($a) as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);

// indicate that this function returns by reference 
// and its argument must be a reference too
function &z(&$a)
{
    return $a;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/mNFkt)

#### Other fixes

To avoid changing the original array, for now, you have the following options:

1. Assign the function result into a temporary variable *before* the `foreach`;
2. Don't use references;
3. Switch to Hack.

Comment: Indeed and according to the manual, this should not work either ~ https://eval.in/172864

Comment: I have confirmed this is fixed in 5.5.19 (ubuntu 14.04 64bit via ppa:ondrej/php5)

Answer (score -1):

In this example, the function z does nothing. It doesn't copy or clone anything therefore the response from z() will be the same as not calling at all. You are simply returning the object passed in and therefore the response is as expected.

```
<?php
$a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
foreach(z($a) as &$x) {
    $x .= 'q';
}
print_r($a);

function z($a)
{
    return $a;
}
```

Thiis is easier to demonstrate using objects as they are given a system ID:

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name = 'foo';

function z($a)
{
    $a->name = 'bar';
    return $a;
}

var_dump($obj);
var_dump(z($obj));
```

The output for this is:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

Both objects have the ID as "1" which shows they are not copies or clones.

Comment: But in PHP, objects are implicitly passed by reference whereas arrays are not (meant to be) so your example is not accurate. You may be on to something with *"the function z does nothing"* though. Could be simply a compiler optimisation at work

Comment: @Phil I agree with Phil that the observed behaviour could be the result of an optimisation that, imho, shouldn't work in this way.

Comment: You are passing and returning references to objects, not objects themselves. The reference is indeed copied.